# Cordova- Error AndroidTarget not installed

Tags: java, android, cordova

I´ve tried to setup Cordova for days now. Without success. I tried every recommended solution google. Nothing worked. And I am close to freaking out now. I hope, you can help me.

When I type Cordova requirements, I get the following error:

"Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
Command failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list target"

It looks like this:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKvmw.png)

I tried the following (As recommended by other posts):

1.) Set Environment variables.

ANDROID_HOME: C:\Users\Micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT: C:\Users\Micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1

Path:

```
  C:\Users\Micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
  C:\Users\Micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\gradle\bin
  C:\Users\Micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
  C:\Users\Micha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin
```

I also tried the Path variables with %ADNROID_HOME%. Same result.

They look like this:
[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha8ib.png) [Other variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2FIN.png)

2.) In Android Studio I added devices with the AVL Manager. I tried API 26, 29 and 30.

3.) In Android Studio I downloaded all the SKD Tools and added a platform for API 29.

3.) I downgraded the JDK Version from 17.0.0 to 16.0.1.

4.) I uninstalled and installed Java 8.